# NLTK label-category classification

Tags: python

i have a csv file with a list of Labels and another file with a list of 20 categories. Is there a way in NLTK to identify which Label belong to which category?

```
 Label

1) Improve your service

2)Who can I contact for technical help?

3) The product I was looking for last week is not listed anymore

4)I would like to return the goods
.
.
.

97) Please call me back asap
```

And the categories are as such

```
1)Communication

2)technical Services

3)Delivery

4)Products
.
.
.
.
.
20) Irrelevant
```

is there a way in NLTK to roughly tell me which category does the label belong to?